# Stuck at EFI Shell version 2.31 [5.8]

Tags: boot, shell, uefi, efi

A friend gave me a pc the other day saying that it can't boot. All i got is that the machine is a vulcan laptop model no VNB11602IS. I tried running some live distros using a USB drive but no luck. Seems that no matter what I try I either enter the SETUP or fall into an EFI shell saying something like the following:

```
EFI Shell version 2.31 [5.8]
Current running mode 1.1.2
Device mapping table
fs0    :HardDisk - Alias hd13b blk0
fs1    ...
blk0   ...
.      ...
.      ...
.      ...
blk7   ...

Shell>
```

I tried preparing USB drives using YUMI and YUMI UEFI but none seem to boot.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how I might be able to proceed... thanks

Comment: While on SETUP can't you change your UEFI option to  legacy or disabled?

Comment: @arana From the setup the only boot options I have are quiet boot and fast boot, both of which are disabled

Comment: some laptops do not give you the full set of configuration options if  you are not using the admin password,some even have different setup for uefi, vulcan site shows 2 methods for entering bios in some devices [https://vulcanelectronics.freshdesk.com/facebook/support/solutions/articles/6000177617-how-to-enter-uefi-bios-windows-10]

Answer (score 1):

[Vulcan has instructions for resetting the laptop](https://support.vulcanelectronics.com/support/solutions/articles/6000079702-how-to-complete-a-factory-reset-on-windows-10-devices), but it presumes you can get to the sign-in screen (though it might be worth a try). You might also check the [WeiHang (Vulcan) manual for other ideas](https://usermanual.wiki/WeiHeng-Digital/VNB11602IS/html). That said, [reviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018AX3YGU) of this PC are not positive.

Comment: I've been scrolling the manual but haven't found anything that helps... What sort of options do I have from the EFI Shell? Is there something I can try from there to diagnose the booting problem?